# iTextSharp 5.5.13: Adding Signature Field to existing PDF

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to add a Signature Field to an existing PDF, but I got two errors, here's my code

```
    private static bool CreateForm(string inputPDF, float x, float y, float w, float h, float angle, bool allPages)
    {
        try
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPDF);
            using (FileStream os = new FileStream(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Temp" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "t0.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                PdfStamper st0 = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, os, '\0', Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Temp" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "t1.pdf", true);

                PdfFormField field = PdfFormField.CreateSignature(st0.Writer);

                field.FieldName = "FIRMA";

                field.SetWidget(new Rectangle(x, y, x + w, y + h), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_OUTLINE);
                field.SetFieldFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);

                field.Rotate = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(angle));

                if (allPages)
                    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                        st0.AddAnnotation(field, i);
                else
                    st0.AddAnnotation(field, reader.NumberOfPages);

                st0.FormFlattening = true;
                st0.Writer.CloseStream = true;
                //st0.Close();

            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

now if I close the stamper `st0.Close()` I got an error of "Signature must be closed", else if I don't close it the resulting file is empty (0 B); tried also without `st0.FormFlattening = true;` and without `st0.Writer.CloseStream = true;`, I haven't found any combination working.

Suggestions?

Comment: This may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734663/use-itext-to-create-signature-with-complete-own-appearance

Comment: If you merely want to add an empty, unsigned signature field, don't start with `PdfStamper st0 = PdfStamper.CreateSignature` but instead use a normal stamper `PdfStamper st0 = new PdfStamper`.